# Multiple definitions error when linking files

Tags: c, makefile, header

I have this header file:

```
 #ifndef COUNT_WORDS_H
    #define COUNT_WORDS_H

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    #define NKEYS (sizeof (keytab)/sizeof (struct key))
    #define MAXWORD 100
    #define BUFSIZE 100

    struct key
    {
        char *word;
        int count;
    } keytab [] = {
        "auto", 0,
        "break", 0,
        "case", 0,
        "while", 0,
    };
    #endif
```

and this Makefile:

```
 all: countWords.o binsearch.o getword.o getch.o countWords.h
        gcc countWords.o binsearch.o getword.o getch.o

    countWords.o: countWords.c binsearch.o getword.o getch.o countWords.h
        gcc -c countWords.c

    binsearch.o: binsearch.c countWords.h
        gcc -c binsearch.c

    getword.o: getword.c getch.o countWords.h
        gcc -c getword.c

    getch.o: getch.c countWords.h
        gcc -c getch.c

    clean:
        -rm -f *.o
```

and I'm getting errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: binsearch.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `keytab'; countWords.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: getword.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `keytab'; countWords.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: getch.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `keytab'; countWords.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
```

What am I doing wrong?  I have the #ifndef in the header file so why is it seeing the struct in the header file more than once?  I don't understand why I'm getting this error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The *linker* found the duplications. The header guard does not prevent the compiler including the header in different compilation units. It protects from including a header multiple times in the same compilation unit. Solution: don't define variables and functions in header files: only declarations.

Comment: And anyway, shouldn't that array start with: `{ .word = "auto", .count = 0 }`?

Comment: that's the way my professor wants it..not sure why.  Thanks for the info though.  I'll keep looking into it

Comment: @xxh not if the data goes into consecutive struct members. Although each pair of data should be braced really, as in `{ "auto", 0 },`

Comment: @WeatherVane C code here, not C++.

Comment: @xhh there is no C++ tag, this is C. You do not need those specifiers.

Comment: @WeatherVane Since when is `{ "auto", 0 }` valid C code?

Comment: `keytab [] = { { "auto", 0}, {"break", 0}, {"case", 0}, {"while", 0} };`. Four elements of array of `struct`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I was in the middle of testing just that, I swore that wasn't C, but, I guess I'm wrong. But the implicit cast from `char const*` to `char*` isn't good.

Comment: @xxh actually I have *never* used field specifiers in the style you showed.

Comment: Thanks everyone...I moved the variable out of the header file and it works.  Really appreciate it

Comment: Info on designated initializers: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html